# convert time to iso format to populate ion-datetime in ionic 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, momentjs, ionic3

I have this in my html:

```
<ion-datetime [(ngModel)]="time" formControlName="time" displayFormat="hh:mm a"></ion-datetime>
```

I want to populate that with the data from the server. The result from http request is in string format:

```
10:00PM
```

I my .ts I have this code to populate:

```
this.time = data.time;
```

In which `data.time = '10:00PM'`

But unfortunately, it give me an Error: invalid ISO Format.

How can I convert `10:00PM` to ISO Format in order to populate the `ion-datetime` with display format of `hh:mm a`?

Please help me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show '10:00PM', you'd need to convert that string to `'22:00'`. With that format, the `ion-datetime` component will preselect the '10:00' hour and the 'PM'.

You can easily do that with [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), like this:

```
moment(yourString, 'h:mm a').format('H:mm');
```

Then, just like you've said, you can adjust the `displayFormat` attribute to be `hh:mm A` like this:

```
<ion-item no-padding color="light">
  <ion-label floating>{{ 'FIELDS.TIME' | translate }}</ion-label>
  <ion-datetime ... displayFormat="hh:mm A"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Glad to hear that :)